# SQL Server 2012 - No process on the other end of the pipe / TCP Provider 'forcibly closed'

Tags: sql-server

```
using sqlcmd

use <database>
go

:r foo.sql
go
```

`foo.sql` contains `INSERT INTO` a table; if `foo.sql` is short, say only 900 rows or so, things work fine; when foo.sql is long; say a 200,000 rows, batched into 900 rows each, the connection is closed.

Advice welcome.

Comment: What means "foo.sql is ... 200,000 rows"? Is it a single short query which selects / inserts / updates or deletes 200,000 records or are there 200,000 selects / inserts / updates or deletes queries in it? How is it batched?

Comment: Stefan, the target table is about 200,000 rows.  The underlying sql is just a set of multiple-row inserts, about 900 rows at a time.  If I just do one or two sets of inserts through sqlcmd, everything works.  If i try to do all of them at once, I get a 'forcibly closed' message if the TCP provider is used, a 'no process' message if the Named Pipes provider is used.  Thanks